# Best way to pass route params between callbacks in expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback

I've tried to search for a similar problem on here but suprisingly couldn't find one posted already.

I use expressjs v4 framework and I'm constructing my routes like this:

```js
'use strict';

let express = require('express');
let router = express.Router();
let users = require('./modules/users');

router.post('/',users.add);

router.put('/edit/:id',users.edit);
```

As you can see above, I'm requiring `let users = require('./modules/users')`

Now the `users` module looks (let's say) like this:

```js
'use strict';
let usersDbModule = require('...');

let users = {
    'add': (req, res, next) => {
         let callback = (err, record) => {
            //...do something
            users.function1(record)
         }
         usersDbModule.save(req, callback);
    },
    'function1': (record) => {
         users.function2()
    },
    'function2': () => {
         //...do something with next() function
    }
}
```

You can notice, that router from the first code block is using module's `add` function. `add` function it's a standard express middleware function but now the things are getting more complicated.

As you can see, `add` function has `next` as one of the params, now I'm doing some complex callbacks calls from different functions and let's say that in the end I want to call `next` in `function2`.

My question is, what is the best way of passing `req`, `res` and `next` params between different callback functions within the same module.

I come up with 3 different methods of doing it:

**Method 1:** 
Pass `req`, `res` or `next` if necessary around to all the functions in the chain so in this case I would have to pass `next` to `callback` than to `function1` and than from `function1` to `function2`.

Not the best way in my opinion, difficult to maintain, read and probably test as well.

**Method 2:** 
Wrap `function1` and `function2` with closures in the `add` passing all the necessary params. In this particular case I would have to wrap only `function2` with closure passing `next` so it would looks something like this:

```js
'add': (req, res, next) => {
    users.function2(next);
    //....rest of the code of the function add
}
```

And than the `function2` itself:

```js
'function2': (next) => {4
   return () => {
       //...now I have access to next here
       // without a need to pass it to each and every
       // function in the chain
   }
}
```

**Method 3:**

Append all the necessary functions/variables to `res.locals` and pass only `res` object around.

It has exactly the same problem as `Method 1` so I would personally be in favour of `Method 2` but not sure if it doesn't make the code less readable and maybe there are some other problems with it, haven't tested it in production nor in development environment with the team.

---

I would really like to hear what are you guys using and how it plays in your projects/teams. Any preferences, best practices, best patterns ? Please share, I really want to know what's the best way.

Maybe there is even better way of doing it ?

All feedback greatly appreciated!

---

**Real life example:**

Example usage for `function1` & `function2` and possibly more...

Let's say we have an adapter that fetches data from an external API, than it needs to save the data into a database, and return a response. Let's also assume that the data returned from the API expires after 5s. If the client hits the route within 5s span, it gets the data from the database, if time between calls was longer, than it repeats the operation calling the API.

This would be of course more complicated than just `function1` and `function2`. It would require a lot of callback functions, both from the adapter and the database, also separate functions for fetching data from the database, adapter, saving data into a database, and eventually deleting data from the database, it gives at least 4 callback functions already.

Answer (score 0):

I think that mix express and app logic is not a good idea.
I use next way in my project

```
// middlewares/auth.js
// Example middleware
exports.isAdmin = function (req, res, next) {
    if (smth-admin-check)
        next();
    else
        next (new Error(403));
}

// routes/index.js
// Include only modules from /routes
let user = require('./user');
let auth = require('../middlewares/auth');
...
app.get('/user/:id(\\d+)', user.get);
app.post('/user', auth.isAdmin, user.post); // only admin can add user

// routes/user.js
// Call model methods and render/send data to browser
// Don't know about db 
let User = require('/models/user');
...
exports.get = function(req, res, next) {
    let id = req.params.id;
    // I cache most data in memory to avoid callback-hell
    // But in common case code like below 
    User.get(id, function(err, u) {
        if (!u)
            return next(new Error('Bad id'));

        ... render page or send json ...
    });
}
...
exports.post = function(req, res, next) { ... } 

// models/user.js
// Encapsulate user logic
// Don't use any express features 
let db = require('my-db');
...
class User {
   get(id, callback) { ... } 
   add(data, callback) { ... } // return Error or new user
   ...
}
```

Comment: Where do you see a mix of logic and express routing ? It is separated, `users.add` function is a `callback` for a route, so `router.post('/',users.add);` is the exact place where I separate app specific logic from express routing.

Additionally, your answer doesn't solve the problem, your example is super simple version skipping `function2` problem completely.

Comment: Can you provide example of purpose for `function1` and `function2`?

Comment: Just updated the anser giving an example at the very bottom. Thanks

Comment: I think that better way is push down a logic of extract data to model. So Express will have one simple callback function to get result like above.